# How to release action in custom device action for android tv?

Tags: action, google-assistant-sdk

I have developed custom device action in android tv. And I want to release the action.json for production.But I always failed in google review.

The custom device action is built in the real device. So it should be not test in the web simulator.

Your submission of version 11 was denied for the following reason:
English - en
Your sample invocations don't consistently invoke your Action.
Note: Thank you for submitting your Assistant Action for review. Unfortunately, your Action has been denied for the following 1. The sample invocation "talk to ***" does not work as it is intended and does not trigger the Action. Please verify that all listed sample invocation phrases work correctly. In this case, whenever we try to invoke your Action we get the message "App isn't installed". We kindly urge you to take a look at your coding and how the Action behaves in the simulator in the AoG console and resubmit when you feel confident that your Action is performing well. Feel free to reach out to our support team if you need help resolving this issue: https://developers.google.com/actions/support/ Visit : https://developers.google.com/actions/distribute/invocation-and-discovery for more information on this topic.

Comment: Is this a custom device Action or Actions on Google?